# How do I change focus within ConfirmDialog?

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane, jpasswordfield

I have a `ConfirmDialog` that pops up asking the user to enter their password.
I inserted a `JPasswordField` into the dialog to conceal the password. That all works fine.

The issue I'm having at the moment is: when the dialog pops up, focus is given to the 'OK' button instead of the `JPasswordField`. As shown below.

[image: Example of focus issue]

I would like to know how I would go about changing the focus from the 'OK' button to the password field.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
        
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, passField, "Enter password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

I have no idea where to go from here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> focus is given to the 'OK' button instead of the JPasswordField.

Check out `RequestFocusListener` found in [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement my own `JDialog` instatn of using `JOptionsPane`

OR you can try something like this:

```
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField()         
{
    public void addNotify()             
    {                 
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocusInWindow();             
    }         
};
```